# How to get facebook user data via Graphi Api using access token offline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I have three users A,B,C. B is mutual friend of A and C... A and B and are users of my application. A is logged in user and B is offline right now whose valid access token is in my DB.

I want to retrieve Name,Picture of User C and I use following code in my browser and it works.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/UserB_ID/friends?access_token=CAAJmeR8cdJ8BA...
```

One way is that I can just parse this Url using file_get_contents... But I am looking for some sophisticated method. I thought of another way as below:

```
$facebook->setAccessToken(AccessTokenOfUserB);
$userFriendsOfFriends_profile = $facebook->api('/UserB_ID/friends?fields=name,location&limit=20');
```

But it doesn't work, will be thankful if I get some hint to solve it.